# Spotfire Scheduled Sharepoint Data Refresh

Tags: sharepoint, spotfire

There does not seem to be a way to set up automatic refreshing of data from Sharepoint like there is with a SQL server.

The main difference from what I can tell is that Sharepoint is only listed as a Data Table, with no Data Connection Settings.

[Data Connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HbOde.png)

[Data Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGvcc.png)

How can I can I set up Spotfire to automatically update the data from Sharepoint once a day? I've tried various JS and IronPython scripts, although not specifically designed for Sharepoint data updates and I've had no luck so far.

Comment: can you clarify a little bit? by default, when you open the analysis, it should be pulling fresh data.

Comment: No, when I open the the Spotfire report the data does not automatically refresh. I have to manually click the Reload Data button in the toolbar.

Comment: when you say "open spotfire" are you opening it in the thick client or the web player? this is kinda new to me, but I haven't worked a lot with sharepoint so..

Comment: PS, it's not really a solution, but you can create an Action Control with a one-line script to refresh on click as a stopgap: `Document.Data.Tables["Data Table"].Refresh()`

Comment: @niko It works in the editable version in my Desktop Spotire, but it doesn't work in the web player, which is where I need it to work. Below is the link to the error code. It was too large to fit in the coment

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1A9LngjwnPhn64qBRE1wdKYxZcQFMn7ECMXDDQ60LZs8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: can you please clarify what you are doing to get this error? it says "Execution of Javascript failed;" what's the Javascript you're using?

Comment: also you can use www.pastebin.com for sharing large blocks of text :) google docs works okay, but pastebin is usually the preferred tool.

Comment: The error only appears in the web viewer. It works in edit mode via Spotfire Desktop

Comment: I understood that from your last comment :) can you clarify your answer to my question please?

Comment: @niko I was using the script you provided me "Document.Data.Tables["Data Table"].Refresh()" with "Data Table" changed to my Data table name. I can't put in the table name online as it would reveal where I work.

Comment: Gotcha. So just to clarify, this is an iron python script. Not sure why it’d throw a JavaScript error but it’s not impossible, but double check that you’ve added it as the correct script type.

Comment: When you’re adding the table, are you adding it from an information link or from a direct connection to the data source? (Also ps, your company name is listed in your second screenshot; if it’s a concern for you, you may wanna edit that out ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had contacted Spotfire support and at the moment is it not possible to do automatic updating from Sharepoint. They may or may not add it in the future.